# Determine which method is dispatched for a particular function call

Tags: r

I'm trying to understand some code I didn't write (`plot.gam` in mgcv), and there's a call to a `plot()` function with some strange parameters that I don't recognize (e.g., "P").  I'd like to figure out which plot method is being dispatched on this call.  `findMethod()` and similar functions don't help (I think plot is `S3`).  I tried the debug library, but that doesn't let you "step into" a function call (and neither does the base debug functions).

Is there any way to monitor all function calls and their associated method dispatches in R?  Or perhaps a function to which I can pass a string containing the actual function call (not just the signature) that will tell me what method gets dispatched?

Comment: Just an aside . . . when specifying parameters in a function call you can truncate the name of the parameter to anything that is unambiguous.  So, if there is only one parameter that _starts_ with a `P` in the signature, you could specify that parameter by `P = `.  This doesn't answer your question, hence the reason it is a mere comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `plot.gam()` we note that `plot()` is called on `x$smooth[[i]]`, which is an object of class:

```
class(x$smooth[[i]])
[1] "tprs.smooth" "mgcv.smooth"
```

There *is* a `plot()` method for class `"mgcv.smooth"` and it is this that is being used for the plot in the general case. `?plot.gam` mentions that this is the default method used for most smooths, but there are specific methods for certain types of smooth supported by `gam()` (from Details section of `?plot.gam`:

> ```
> For smooth terms ‘plot.gam’ actually calls plot method functions
> depending on the class of the smooth. Currently random effect and
> Markov random field smooths have special methods, the rest use the
> defaults described below.
> ```

For some reason, `methods()` is not finding these methods, but they do exist:

```
> mgcv:::plot.mgcv.smooth
function (x, P = NULL, data = NULL, label = "", se1.mult = 1, 
    se2.mult = 2, partial.resids = FALSE, rug = TRUE, se = TRUE, 
    scale = -1, n = 100, n2 = 40, pers = FALSE, theta = 30, phi = 30, 
    jit = FALSE, xlab = NULL, ylab = NULL, main = NULL, ylim = NULL, 
    xlim = NULL, too.far = 0.1, shade = FALSE, shade.col = "gray80", 
    shift = 0, trans = I, by.resids = FALSE, scheme = NULL, ...) 
{
....
```

This may be related to a bug in `methods()` that meant `plot.function` was not shown in the list and my current R might not incorporate that fix. This method should be shown normally, and the general advice in such situations would be to identify the class of object (as I showed above) and then use `methods()` and similar functions (e.g. `showMethods()`) to identify if specific methods available for the class(es) of the object returned.

Comment: Yep, that was my problem--it didn't show up in methods().  But this is right--thanks!

Answer (score 3):

For S3 classes, `methods("plot")` will give all the methods defined for a particular function.  As an S3 dispatch, the one called will be based on the class of the first argument.  Looking at `plot.gam`, I assume that the part you are asking about starts `plot(x$smooth[[i]])`, so you need to see what the class of `x$smooth[[i]]` is (where `x` is the object `gam` object) to determine what `plot` method will be called.

I don't know of a way to do this automatically.

Comment: I had tried doing exactly this.  I know that x$smooth[[i]] is of class mgcv.smooth, but I'm not sure how, with an S3 class, I can go from knowing that to knowing which plot() gets dispatched.  There's nothing specific that jumps out from a methods() call.  If this were S4, then something like getMethod() and the class signature would work.  But I'm not sure what to do with an S3 method.  (I manually examined all visible plot functions, and nothing looked right.)

Comment: Typo: `methods`, not `method`.

Answer (score 0):

Print the class of the object from inside the function. Either hack the function or use trace().