# How to test if object has a particular method?

Tags: r, oop

If a function receives an arbitrary object `x` as argument, what's the best way to test whether `x` supports some method `foo`?

(I thought that, as a last resort, the function could always just attempt to evaluate `foo(x)` within a `tryCatch` with suitable handlers, but I discovered that, at least in some cases, `foo(x)` will not produce an error even if `x` does not support `foo`; instead it will just return `NULL`.  Therefore, one cannot rely on catching an exception as a suitable test of `x`'s support of `foo`.)

I imagine that the answer to this question will depend on `x`'s "object flavor" (`S3`, `S4`, or whatever).  Please consider all such possibilities in your answer.

Answer (score 5):

There are several ways to approach this.

Find available methods via:

```
methods(class = class(x))
```

Test if `foo` method exists for class of `x`:

```
"foo" %in% methods(class = class(x))
```

If your methods are not exported by a package (and only accessible via `package:::foo.bar(x)` where `bar` is the class of `x`), they will not be revealed in the example above.

---

See also [In R, how to find out which method is dispatched for a particular function call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7195628/in-r-how-to-find-out-which-method-is-dispatched-for-a-particular-function-call/7196152#7196152)

Answer (score 2):

You may want to explore the output of `methods`.  For instance

```
head(attr(methods("print"), "info"))
              visible                          from generic  isS4
print.acf       FALSE registered S3method for print   print FALSE
print.anova     FALSE registered S3method for print   print FALSE
print.aov       FALSE registered S3method for print   print FALSE
print.aovlist   FALSE registered S3method for print   print FALSE
print.ar        FALSE registered S3method for print   print FALSE
print.Arima     FALSE registered S3method for print   print FALSE
```

A quick and dirty test for if a method exists for a class of object would be

```
has_method <- function(class, method){
  method_list <- methods(print)
  method_list <- rownames(attr(method_list, "info"))

  any(grepl(paste0(class, "$"), method_list))
}

has_method("stepfun", "print")
```