# Difficulty in understanding `[[a, b, c]]` syntax (in igraph)

Tags: r, igraph

I am new to R and I just came across this example:

```
library(igraph)
library(sand)
data(USairports)
USairports[["BOS", "JFK", edges = TRUE]]
```

How `[[]]` in this example works? As I know, `[[]]` is used to access single element in list, but why can we pass 3 parameters to it? It looks like matrix/function. Thanks.

Comment: See `help("[[.igraph")`

Comment: That's exactly what I want! Thanks.

Comment: More generally, see also `?methods` and e.g. this answer: [Determine which method is dispatched for a particular function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7195628/determine-which-method-is-dispatched-for-a-particular-function-call/7196071#7196071).  Thus, if you do `methods("[[") `, you will get a list of all available methods for `[[`. In your case, when `igraph` is loaded, you will find `[[.igraph*`, `[[.igraph.es*`, and `[[.igraph.vs*`. Which you then search for their help texts.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very nice question!

You really can use more indexes and arguments.

### Data frames

When you refer to rows and columns of a data frame, double brackets will drop eventual names and allow you to choose only a single element.

So e.g. for data frames you can use both:

```
mtcars[2, 3]
mtcars[[2, 3]]
```

but:

```
# OK
mtcars[2:3, 3:4]
#               disp  hp
# Mazda RX4 Wag  160 110
# Datsun 710     108  93

# NOT WORKING
mtcars[[2:3, 3:4]]
# Error in col[[i, exact = exact]] : 
#   attempt to select more than one element in vectorIndex
```

There are additional arguments that can be passed in double square brackets, see [documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extract.html) or type `?"[["` in R console.

### Lists

For lists, you can use only one index to refer to an element of a list.

```
data <- as.list(mtcars)
data[[1]]
# or:
data[["mpg"]]
data$mpg
```

(See [documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extract.html) or type `?"[["` in R console.)

### igraph

However, with `USairports` you are using special `igraph` class, which is a type of list and it works slightly different (you can use more indexes and e.g. the `edges` attribute is specific for igraph).

So your example:

```
USairports[["BOS", "JFK", edges = TRUE]]
```

is to get the edge IDs between two vertices (from `BOS` to `JFK` here).

See [igraph documentation](https://igraph.org/r/doc/sub-sub-.igraph.html).